# Pinescript: expression argument of security has no side effects error

Tags: pine-script

I am calling a function using the following:

```
[v01, c01, d01] = security("NSE:NIFTY", timeframe.period, funct())
```

I am getting an error " Expression argument of security function should have no side effects"

However it works with `[v01, c01, d01] = funct()`

What is my mistake?

Comment: Please provide a full script to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Debugged it. Was trying to plot inside a function. Once removed, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugged it with the help of another coder friend. Was trying to plot inside a function. Once removed, it works fine. –